# How to save for Adhoc on Xcode 7 b6?

Tags: ios, xcode7, adhoc

Xcode 6 has these options when you export an archive:

[image]

But Xcode 7 has just two options and "Save for Ad Hoc Development", that is the one I want, is not there.

How do I save for Ad Hoc Development on Xcode 7?

Comment: Xcode 7b6 has "Save for Ad Hoc Development" on my machine. Maybe something about your project preventing it?

Comment: I don't see it either, did anything work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the problem is that you don't have an Ad Hoc distribution provision? I'm using Xcode 7 and Save for Ad Hoc Deployment is present on my machine:

[image]

Comment: I have. This is probably some Xcode stupid error. I will install Xcode again. Thanks.

Comment: And if that doesn't bring it back, for heaven's sake report this as a bug to Apple! I've shown you what this dialog _should_ look like, so if it doesn't, something's wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be an issue with cocoapods for me, solution was to upgrade to the beta `0.39.0.beta.4` as described here https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4087